# angular2 how to make route as default route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 rc.4-5

I have following route configuration.

how can i make any route as default route, so when page get loaded it goes to hello component **without redirecting**.

```
    let routes: RouterConfig = [

                {
                    path: 'hello',
                    component: HelloComponent
                },
                /*{
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: '/hello',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                },*/
                {
                    path: 'increment',
                    component: IncComponent
                },{
                    path: 'adder',
                    component: AdditionComponent
                },{
                    path: 'roman',
                    component: RomanComponent
                }
            ];
router.resetConfig(this.routes);
```

Comment: What's the problem with redirecting? That's how it's done in the new router.

Comment: problem with redirecting is, i am using Async loading of components and on pageload they don't know if route exist or not

Comment: I am following the Angular documentation about the new Router and RC5 and I don't want to redirect. There isn't any requirements of redirecting. Now I am facing the following problem. In `app.module` I am bootstrapping the `AppComponent` and I have in `app.router` two additional routes (crisis-center and heroes). And I am getting this error: Cannot match any routes: ''   I want to have `AppComponent` like home page. If I add a route { path:'', component: AppComponent} than I'm seeing `AppComponent` twice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters in your routes so make sure the "default" route is first. if you want HelloComponent to be your default page then set your router like this....

```
{path:'', component: HelloComponent},
{path:'increment', component: IncrementComponent}
```

and so on

Comment: HelloComponent may also have its own path like 'hello' then i have make one more entry like {path:'hello', component: HelloComponent} which i want to avoid

Comment: no the point of a default is that you dont add that extra path route. so anytime you want redirect to Hellocomponent you specify the path or route as  "blank" as in just ''

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this for more detail read it over [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html) under **`Matching Strategy`** heading

```
[{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'prefix', //default
  redirectTo: 'main'
},
{
  path: 'main',
  component: Main
}]
```